# ui-router wizard Id in URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a wizard based process for creating quotes.  I'm using angularjs ui-router to manage the wizard urls.  The routes shown below work fantastic for creating a new quote.  I now need to go back in to edit existing quotes and need to figure out how to use the ID in the URL.  I was thinking something like baseUrl/quote#/3/options (quote #3 options step).  Currently the url looks like baseUrl/quote#/options.  If I change the url in the .state definition from url: 'options', to url:':quoteId/options' it breaks my routes (can no longer get to the option step).  Also this wouldn't work for a new quote since it doesn't yet have an ID.  What's the best way to get this to work?

```
quoteWizardModule.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('wizard', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/quoteWizard/wizardLayout.html',
            controller: 'wizardNavigationCtrl'
        })
        .state('wizard.options', {
            url: 'options',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/quoteWizard/wizardOptions.html',
            controller: 'wizardOptionsCtrl'
        })
        .state('wizard.newmodel', {
            url: 'newmodel',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/quoteWizard/wizardModel.html',
            controller: 'wizardModelCtrl',
        })
        .state('wizard.model', {
            url: 'model/:factoryId/:index',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/quoteWizard/wizardModel.html',
            controller: 'wizardModelCtrl'
        })
        .state('wizard.other', {
            url: 'other',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/quoteWizard/wizardOther.html',
            controller: 'wizardOtherCtrl'
        })
        .state('wizard.customer', {
            url: 'customer',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/quoteWizard/wizardCustomer.html',
            controller: 'wizardCustomerCtrl'
        })
        .state('wizard.shipping', {
            url: 'shipping',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/quoteWizard/wizardShipping.html',
            controller: 'wizardShippingCtrl'
        })
        .state('wizard.notes', {
            url: 'notes',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/quoteWizard/wizardNotes.html',
            controller: 'wizardNotesCtrl'
        })
        .state('wizard.review', {
            url: 'review',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/quoteWizard/wizardReview.html',
            controller: 'wizardReviewCtrl'
        });
}]);
```

Comment: funny, just came accross this article http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router and saw your question

Comment: the article seems to do a lot of the same things I do but doesn't address reloading the wizard.. I wonder if it's not typical and I should not make the URL include the ID.  I could easily just load the state of the form (it's kept in a service) and keep the URL's the same, without an ID.  This wouldn't allow you to go to any particular place in the wizard with a URL only, but maybe that's not  necessary.

Comment: you totally can use id in url, that is valid situation. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#$stateParams shows (stateParameters section) show example like that in the very end